# MySQL Escape double quotes in query result

Tags: mysql, escaping, concatenation, quotes

I have a CONCATENATION problem regarding quotes.
In my database I have single and double quoted text and then I buld a JSON string with CONCAT,

```
CONCAT('{"',a,'":"',b,'"}')
```

Lets say we have the following data:

```
a           b
Phrase      Monica's mirror
Phrase      Joe "Hammer" Smith
Phrase      Oo-la-laaa
```

The concatenation will be

```
{"Phrase":"Monica's mirror"}
{"Phrase":"Joe "Hammer" Smith"}
{"Phrase":"Oo-la-laaa"}
```

As you can see 'Joes "Hammer" Smith' will create an invalid json string.

### QUESTION

Is there a way in SQL to escape quotes (in the CONCAT)? so I get this result:

```
{"Phrase":"Monica's mirror"}
{"Phrase":"Joe \"Hammer\" Smith"}
{"Phrase":"Oo-la-laaa"}
```

Remember, this is not on the PHP side, it needs to be done in the SQL query,
Thank you...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
CONCAT('{"',REPLACE(a,'"','\\"'),'":"',REPLACE(b,'"','\\"'),'"}')
```

Comment: I found the same function while I was waiting for an answer :) You confirmed that I was on the right track! Thank you.

Comment: It't to too late for me now, I saw I had already used that solution in one query... Time to hit the bed I guess :P Thanks anyway!